# img src won't work with php variables

Tags: php, variables, image, src

```
<a href="'.$productLink.'" alt="'.$productName.'">
<img src="'.$productImg1URL.'" alt="'.$productName.' '.$productType.' ">
</a>
```

Hello the img src is actually in a different directory /images

I know this is probably super easy but Ive spent an hour on it and nothing.  The page works but doesn't show the directory. Please help the rookie. I took out the < in front of the a href and img src couldn't make the page display

Comment: What do you see when you go to "view source" in your browser and look at this piece of the page?  Can you manually copy and paste the img tag's src url and load it in the browser?

Comment: BTW: you should always use htmlspecialchars() when inserting text in HTML, otherwise e.g. quotes in product name will break your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Job #1 when you have a problem with code that is generating HTML, is look at the output source and compare it with what you expect.  I've had problems like this before and they usually vanished when I stopped thinking about the PHP code, and looked at the actual output.

What is the content of $productImg1URL - and if the images that it's referencing are in the URL starting /images/ - does that start $productImg1URL.  If it's just the name of an image, but without the path - you have to put that into place.

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways of doing this:

Firstly, outside of a code block:

```
<?php
// code here
?>
<a href="<?= $productLink ?>" alt="<?= $productName ?>">
<!-- or -->
<img src="<?echo $productImgURL; ?> alt="<?php echo $productName . ' ' . $productType ?>">
</a>
```

The first form is called the [short open tag](http://au.php.net/ini.core) and has to be enabled in your php.ini which it almost always is.

Or if you're doing this inside a code block:

```
<?php
echo <<<END
<a href="$productLink" alt="$productName">
<img src="$productImgLURL" alt="$productName $productType">
</a>
END
```

The `<<<END` is a [heredoc](http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and I usually prefer it to using a big string within double quotes, which requires escaping contained double quotes.