# Facebook-like profile pictures php

Tags: php

I have a forum website.

I am developing profile images and I am sort of stuck.

I have a code that returns profile pictures but only your profile image and if your logged into your account, it doesn't work to view your image on another account.

Basically, I don't really know how to explain it in words, but a Facebook like profile pictures feel where your profile picture can be seen by others and vice versa.

Also the login-user name table is different to the name posted in the answer. They have been both been mysql_fetch_assoc to the variable $row. Imagelocation is where the profile image is stored, a_name is where the user posts their name in the answer and name is where the user is in general login terms.

```
        $name = $_SESSION['name_of_user'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fgusers3 WHERE name='$name'");
       $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
       $location = $row['imagelocation'];
```

That is the code at the top of the page, queries etc. Below is the row in the table i  am trying to add the profile images to.

```
       <td width="12%" style=";" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><? if ($rows['a_name'] == $row['name'] ) {
echo "<img src='$location' width='100' height='100'>";
      }  ?></td>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. You might also be vulnerable to second-order SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the question correctly, your having trouble with embedding the url in the src attribute of the image tag with php. If that's the case, the answer to your question lies in the link below. Location should be a url, you just have to escape it properly so that it shows up in the format html expects. Take a look at your html and see what is being generated.

[img src won't work with php variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693698/img-src-wont-work-with-php-variables)

Comment: is that what is wrong with the code, i don't know tbh. I have just tested out the above code and found that only an image is echoed for me and not for anyone else

Comment: If you clarify your problem a little more you will get better answers. Was sort of hard to figure out what you were asking. Are you trying to display more pictures?  Do you have them saved in a database? What do you mean an image is not echoed for anyone else? If the image isnt echoed for other users there must be something wrong with the links that you are pulling for them. Check the HTML output to be sure.